# how to send and receive objects or values using JQuery-AJAX, JSON and php?

Tags: php, json, jquery

How can I send and receive values?

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

jQuery: on click of save button

```
$("#budget_submit").click(function(){       
        var budget = $("#budget_cardno").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            url: 'budget.php',
            data: budget,
            success: function(data){
                if(data.success == true)
                alert(data.message);
        }
        });
    });
```

html:

```
<form method="post" id="budgetform">
   <fieldset>
      <ul>
    <li>
      <label>CARD NUMBER</label>
      <input name="budget_cardno" id="budget_cardno" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>MONTHLY BUDGET</label>
      <input name="budget_monthly" id="budget_monthly" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input class="submit" id="budget_submit" name="budget_submit" type="submit" value="Save"/>
        </li>
      </ul>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

Php:

```
<?php 
$dbhost = '#';
$dbuser = '#';
$dbpass = '#';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$cardNo = $_POST['budget'];     #This statement does not work.
if($cardNo == "")
{
    mysql_close($conn);
    $data = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'ENTER DETAILS');
    echo json_encode($data);
}

else
{
}
?>
```

how can I send the value budget to the PHP file and store it in $cardNo and return the message?

I don't want to check for the condition at the client side because I have other conditions to check which needs data from database.

Comment: you can check the $_POST received by the php script by using echo print_r($_POST); it will tell you the key and the value of the data received (if any). I don'T see any trouble at first glance. You might want to consider using cosole tools like firebug or something similar to see what is sent and retuned.

Answer (score 1):

actually this seems weird to me.

```
if($cardNo == "")
{
    mysql_close($conn);
    $data = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'ENTER DETAILS');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

This will trigger only if the value is EMPTY. So if you send a value, it won't trigger since the statement is false.
Change your == to != so it state: if $cardNo IS NOT EMPTY like so:

```
if($cardNo != "")
{
    mysql_close($conn);
    $data = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'ENTER DETAILS');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: further more, i sugest you start using mysqli instead of mysql as it is (or soon will be) deprecated.

Comment: I'm just checking whether the code works for empty value. The actual condition is different from the one I posted.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're treating the incoming data as a normal form, when in fact you're sending JSON. PHP is therefore not finding any $_POST parameter with name 'budget'.

You need to get the raw post data using `file_get_contents('php://input');` and then use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert it into an object. From it you could then get the `budget` parameter.

So something like this should work:

```
$formdata = file_get_contents('php://input');
$formdata_obj = json_decode($formdata);

$cardNo = $formdata_obj->budget;
```

If you're actually just sending one value (as you seem to be doing) the first line alone might suffice, because the whole data would be the value itself rather than a JSON encoded object:

```
$cardNo = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: Just saw the same thing over here.

Comment: @jbx: how to use file_get_contents('php://input');

Comment: @jbx: $requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
$requestBody = json_decode($requestBody);

$cardNo = $requestBody -> budget;

Comment: Yeah, but it has to be json_decode() not jsonDecode(), and don't use the same variable for 2 different things ($requestBody) it just confuses you. Why don't you copy my example?

Comment: If it still doesn't work put some 'echo' lines here and there to see what you are receiving in the file_get_contents (to make sure that you are really receiving the JSON), and maybe use var_export() to view the contents of the object generated from `json_decode()`. We've put you on the right track, we can't debug your application!

Comment: @jbx: It says Trying to get property of non-object to $cardNo line

Comment: Are you sure you are actually receiving the data? Try to print out the contents of `$formdata` first. Then try to print out a `var_export($formdata, true)`. This way you verify you're getting the right things in each step.

Comment: It could be that since you're actually sending one value, its not even a JSON object, but just a string with the budget. So you might find that $formdata is in fact already the budget value and you don't need to do any further json_decode() calls. Only debugging properly will help you understand.